# Can I run an PySide2 application as a Windows Background Process

Tags: python, python-3.6, pyside2

I want that the app accept an input from the user and then go into the background as a Windows Background Process. So, is that even possible? If yes then how?

I am using Python 3.6.8 and the PySide2 gui framework

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can run an external background process with `pythonw.exe`. You will have to run it by using `subprocess` or via [Qprocess](https://srinikom.github.io/pyside-docs/PySide/QtCore/QProcess.html) in pyside.

```
import subprocess
subprocess.run(["pythonw.exe", "path/to/your/program"])
```

This will run your program in the background with no visible process or way to interact with it. You can only terminate it with a system monitor